# WPF UserControl Inheritence: namespace not found

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

I'm following [this article](http://jamescrisp.org/2008/05/26/wpf-control-inheritance-with-generics/).

I have a user control that looks like this:

```
<common:ViewBase
    x:Class="MyNamespace.MyView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:common="clr-namespace:Common;assembly=Common">
</common:ViewBase>
```

My code behind looks like this:

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    public partial class MyView : ViewBase
    {
        public MyView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

ViewBase looks like this:

```
namespace Common
{
    public class ViewBase : UserControl
    {
    }
}
```

But it refuses to build, I keep getting the following error:
The type "common:ViewBase" was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all reference assemblies have been built.

I moved ViewBase to a separate assembly following some advice from another post, but I have also tried putting it in the same assembly. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: What namespace do ViewBase and MyView belong to?

Comment: Generics don't belong into the UI. Create generic ViewModels and leave Views alone. That article is from someone who doesn't know MVVM.

Comment: @JeremiahDotNet updated to show namespaces

Comment: If you change `MyNamespace` to `Common` for the `MyView` class does it compile?

Comment: @HighCore I'm more interested in getting the UserControl inheritance to work

Comment: @JUstin984 you usually don't really need that in WPF. Anyways put your base classes in a separate assembly, and rebuild the solution.

Comment: @Justin984 also make sure that the `Target Framework` is the same in both projects.

Comment: @HighCore I have tried a separate assembly, same error

Comment: Are you sure it's failing to build, or is it just showing you what appear to be build errors? The XAML designer often breaks and shows bogus errors that don't actually prevent you from building and running.

Comment: @nmclean Ya, definitely not building. I can not run the application

Comment: Could it be a naming conflict? There's also a .Net class called `ViewBase`. Try to prefix your class with the `Common` namespace in the `MyView` class definition: `public partial class MyView : Common.ViewBase`

Answer (score 1):

I was able to compile using your code as an example and having a separate assembly. If you put it in a separate assembly, you will have to make sure that gets built before your derived UserControl will work. If it is in a separate assembly, verify you have the correct references for a UserControl. I had to add PresentationCore, PresentationFramework, System.Xaml, and WindowsBase before that project would build. In order to get that to build with the references, I had to exclude the derived UserControl from the other project.

This was a chicken & egg scenario. After I got the other assembly to build, I was then able to build the assembly the derived UserControl lived.

If you do not have the base UserControl in a separate assembly, verify the Xaml namespace is correct:

```
xmlns:common="clr-namespace:Common;assembly=Common" // separate assembly
xmlns:common="clr-namespace:Common" // same assembly
```

If you're still having trouble, please post more code and/or more error messages if you have more than one. It could be another error message is the real culprit here.

Answer (score 1):

I had been battling with the same issue for two weeks now and was desperate.

Mine was about loading a complete window as a UserControl with xmlns:local="clr-namespace:myPresentationLayernamespace" and <local:MyUCWindow />. Nothing worked.

After several sessions with Bing, it redirected me to this post and its clue:

> I had to add PresentationCore, PresentationFramework, System.Xaml, and WindowsBase before that project would build.

Actually, I only found - and installed - `System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.UI.Xaml` nuget extension, and the result was instantaneous: *all building errors disappeared*.

I did not have to move any component out of the project. Just installed the extension. Very happy with this post and Bing´s assistance.